# 400 Bad Request when using RestTemplate.postForObject to call API

Tags: java, spring, post, resttemplate

I am trying to post data to my api using RestTemplate, but it returns 400 bad request exception when posting.
How could i fix it?

```
public void postDataToApi(List<String> accountIds, String myApiUrl) {
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
  String accountIdsJsonList = mapper.writeValueAsString(accountIds);
  HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(accountIdsJsonList, headers);
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  String result = restTemplate.postForObject(myApiUrl, entity, String.class);
}
```

Api that i want to post data is YahooApi

https://ads-developers.yahoo.co.jp/reference/ads-search-api/v4/BudgetOrderService/get/en/

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: Without knowing the API you're talking to, we can only guess. 400 is an HTTP error code sent by the webserver on the other end, it's telling you that the request you sent could not be understood. It might be missing headers, malformed JSON, or pretty much anything else that does not match more specific 4xx error codes.

Comment: @JohannesH. I am trying to post accountIds to this Yahoo Api, of course it has authentication

https://ads-developers.yahoo.co.jp/reference/ads-search-api/v4/BudgetOrderService/get/en/

Comment: The documentation you jsut linked clearly states when the API will reply with 400: `114 Invalid scope. The access token is invalid.`. No other reason for a 400 is listed. so, I'd assume it's that. And I don't see you setting any authorization header in your code either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to set accountIds in map. Right now you are directly posting list as json request without key. As we can see from API doc
[image]

Try this

```
public void postDataToApi(List<String> accountIds, String myApiUrl) {
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  Map<String, Object> reqBody = new HashMap<>();
  reqBody.put("accountIds", accountIds);
  headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
  String accountIdsJsonList = mapper.writeValueAsString(reqBody);
  HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(accountIdsJsonList, headers);
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  String result = restTemplate.postForObject(myApiUrl, entity, String.class);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems API Gateway team (another team) is setting an invalid token to request. When access token is valid, i will try with your solution. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The API (yahoo) you have mentioned is accepting only authorized requests. So yahoo API is expecting only the secure requests with either token (generate token first & send it in each reqest) or client_id & client_secret (both in combination to authorize request).

Comment: Thank you. I contacted with API Gateway team to be sure that access token is valid.